# Attempting to upgrade HDD in a Lenovo S400 to an SSD but it doesn’t seem to work

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, laptop, ssd, bios

I am trying to replace my Lenovo S400 Touch HDD (Windows 10) with a new SSD (Windows 7).

When I put the SSD the laptop will stop at Lenovo logo and won't continue to boot. It won't even go to BIOS setup etc.

Before I removed the HDD—that was running Windows 10—I setup the BIOS to legacy support.

Any idea on how to replace HDD of Lenovo S400 touch?

Comment: "I setup the BIOS to legacy support." - Why did you do this?

Comment: What make and model ssd did you buy?

Comment: How did you install Windows 7 onto the SSD? That matters somehow

Comment: You should NOT install windows 7 on any machine anymore. It is a 10 year old OS which is EOL for nearly a year now.

Comment: @mashuptwice HA! The community bot gotcha! .. look at the date of that post ..

Answer (score 0):

It should give an error about finding no bootable drives in either UEFI or legacy boot.Can you confirm that the SSD is fully functional in another system as a faulty drive can lock up a computer at POST.

Answer (score 0):

**Way 1**  Maybe the SSD is not installed properly, try to reinstall the SSD hard drive. If we reinstall the SSD, we can enter the BIOS, but can't see the SSD, it may be a SSD hardware problem, we can put it on other computers to test it. It may also be a problem with the BIOS, we need to update the BIOS.

**Way 2** Does the Windows 7 support UEFI or MBR boot mode? If Windows 7 support UEFI boot mode.
We can try the following way:

1. Put HDD back to Lenovo S400 Touch.
2. Go to BIOS, turn off **Secure Boot**.
3. Then it will display **legacy boot** and **UEFI boot**.
4. Turn off the laptop, replace Lenovo S400 Touch HDD (Windows 10) with a new SSD (Windows 7).
5. Try to reboot, view if we can boot successfully.

[image]

**Way 3**  If the Windows 7 supports MBR boot mode, we do not need to try the way 2. If we can see SSD in BIOS after reinstalling the SSD hard drive (click F1 key), we can try to fix the boot.

**Way 4**  Reinstall the windows 7 operating system, if it supports UEFI boot mode, we can refer the article: [How to install Windows 10 from USB with UEFI support](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-windows-10-usb-bootable-media-uefi-support)

[How to Upgrade Your Laptop’s Hard Drive to an SSD](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/ssd-upgrade-tutorial)

Comment: Note: win7 does support UEFI boot mode, but only if you use the DVD or if you manually move the boot.efi files on the USB pendrive you install from. And obviously only if booted in EFI mode,

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem before removing the SSD. I tried all suggested solutions with no chance. It seems that certain SSDs only work with ideapads "touch"!
My SSD was a brand new ADATA and once replaced with Samsong it boots with no problems. ADATA functions well with other PCs and laptops but no way with ideapad touch!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).